# Is using MD5 in NTLMv2 protocol to store Windows passwords is secure?

Tags: passwords, windows, hash, md5

I read that Windows (probably not new OSs but say, Windows Server 2008) stores passwords using Hashes using NTLMv2 protocol which uses MD5 hash function. My questions: MD5 is known to be insecure because it is not collision resistant. How is it used in Windows 2008 server?

Comment: See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17672/windows-7-password-hash-security?rq=1

Comment: MD5 isn't a poor password hash because of its broken collision resistance. It's a poor password hash because it is *fast*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collisions are irrelevant to most usages of hash functions in conjunction with passwords. For password hashing, *preimage resistance* is important, not collision resistance. MD5's resistance to preimages is (almost) as good as new.

MD5 for password storage would be a poor choice "alone", though, because password hashing requires salts and slowness, both characteristics that MD5 does not offer. See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) for a primer on password hashing.

[NTLMv2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager#NTLMv2) does *not* use MD5 to store passwords. What is stored is a "password-equivalent" value called "NT-hash", which is the hash of the password with MD4, not MD5. No, this is not weak; for that specific usage, MD4 is still fine. As for MD5, it is used within [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) as part of the challenge-response protocol, but not for anything that is *stored*.

There is no known attack against HMAC/MD5. The known MD5 weaknesses void the "warranty": the security proof which guarantees (mathematically) that HMAC is secure relies on the compression function of the underlying hash function: that compression function must be a [PRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family). The known collision attacks on MD5 demonstrate that MD5's compression function is *not* a PRF; however, this does not break HMAC/MD5. This just breaks the security proof. HMAC/MD5 cannot be "proven strong". It just fell into the wider category of "we don't know how to break that".